# How do I do a find or du without getting permission denied errors

Tags: permission, root

Typical example:

```
sudo du -xm /System/Volumes/Data | sort -n -o .all-du                                          
Password:
du: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.aned: Operation not permitted
du: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db: Operation not permitted
du: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/appinstalld: Operation not permitted
...
```

This [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92640/37153) asked how to filter them out but I would like to figure out some way to gain permission to search everything on my disk. I don't plan to muck with Apple's private stuff directly but it might help me to figure out what I can do to free up the space.

The `du` command is just an example.  I have the same problems with `find` and `ls` and any other command that tries to inspect protected areas on the disk.

Comment: Would https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space help (it won't show you the content of the directories listed above, but all the others)?

Comment: Relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/367158/24324, especially [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/whats-system-volumes-data#comment576247_367159). I assume your end goal is to accurately determine the space usage on your mac, for that [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/24324) has some highly voted answers.

Comment: This isn't a question about salvaging disk space.  It is a question about not getting `Operation not permitted` errors.  @Alin Panaitiu's answer below is what I was looking for.  Thank you @Alin Panaitiu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a command running with `sudo` throws `Operation not permitted`, that usually means that the file in question is protected by [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection).

SIP can be disabled easily, here are the instructions from the Apple website linked above:

> To disable SIP, do the following:
>
> 1. Restart your computer in Recovery mode.
> 2. Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu.
> 3. Run the command csrutil disable.
> 4. Restart your computer.

Note that Apple recommends to re-enable SIP as soon as you finish your privileged task:

> #### Warning
>
> Disable SIP only temporarily to perform necessary tasks, and reenable it as soon as possible. Failure to reenable SIP when you are done testing leaves your computer vulnerable to malicious code.